# Can't find the "Reassign loop parameter" node in animation nodes addon

Tags: animation-nodes

I'm using blender-2.81a with the animation nodes add-on (V2.1.6) .

The animation nodes documentation says that in order to change loop values while iterating I need to use the Reassignment Operator node but I can't seem to find it anywhere ....

https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/subprograms/loop.html#reassignment-operators

can someone please point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a node you can directly invoke with the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> submenu. Here is how to do it :

- Create your loop and click it to select it
- Assign a **parameter**
- Go to the right-side panel (shortcut <kbd>N</kbd>, or click on the arrow on the right side of the animation nodes node tree)
- Go to the "Node" subpanel
- Click on the "Reassign" button next to the parameter socket
- Click in the node tree window where you want to place the "reassign" node

[image]

If you want to have the "Condition" boolean operator in the node, you should :

- Select the "Reassign" node
- Go to the "Item" subpanel on the right
- Turn on the computer screen icon next to the "Condition" input socket.

This works for all the animation nodes which may have hidden input/output sockets

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much !!!!!

Comment: I recommend following some videos by Zach Hixson and Chris Prenninger and his lovely german accent on Youtube if you want to kick-start your use of AN !

Comment: Already stumbled across Chris Prenninger & he has some very good stuff . will be sure to keep tuned & check out Zach Hixsons tuts in the process as well (a brief runthrough looks very promising) . can't thank you enough for the help ...