# Animation Nodes : Use Previous output of a Loop in calculation of the next iteration

Tags: animation-nodes

What i am trying to achieve :

- Random floating floors (square plane)
- floating stairs connecting to each of them (Line generator with steps)
- all floating floors have another floor which is parallel to it so the stairs are straight and  only going up or down

What i have achieved so far

- Object instances get vertical elevation from index of loop
- Random number to either or X or Y axis by using boolean switch

The problem :

all the planes are shifted from origin rather than using the location of the previous plane as starting point

So, is there a a way for the loop to get the location of the previous plane and offset the next plane in X or Y ?

[image]

For the stairs I'm planning to use line generator in start/end/step mode in loop to generate locations for the stair instances

Comment: Add a new parameter of type Vector and reassign it at the end of your loop following this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/166868/86891

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using *'reassign'*.

This is an option accessible from the 'loop subprogram' and which allow to obtain a node from which you can reassign an input parameter from some calculated result inside the subprogram.

- Select the subprogram.
- Go into the properties on the right, in the node tab, then click *'reassign'* for the input you want.
- That generates a reassign node, place it in the grid.

[image]

Now you can connect its input from the calculation you want (here probably the loop result).

[image]